# Why my html don't show third column

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I have to display a combo box in the third column of first row. 
My current html code has
First row which contains 3 columns. In first column I have an image and in second column I have a text and in third column I again have a table which contains 2 columns one contains text and another column contains 
combobox. So this was all about first row, Now in second row I just have 1 column and it renders a google map with column span.

I have two problems now:

1. The third column of first row is not shown in the given dimension (I dont know why?) why it just show 2 columns only ? How to make all 3 columns display in first row.
2. How to create event on selection change of that combo in Javascript ?

My code to do this is:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <table border="1" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:30%;max-width:30%;">
                <img src="Image.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:100px;height:50px">
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%; max-width:30%;">
                <h2> List1 </h2>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%; max-width:30%; ">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h2>List2: </h2>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="example">
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">A</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

How to solve these two problems ?

Comment: I cannot understand your problem. Because third column is visible in my browser correctly. May be you can remove `overflow:hidden` to check if that is the problem. And for your second question you add `<select name="example" onchange="myfunction();">`.

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/0j5hgx0k/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you have defined one column with 2 colspans, which it is 1*2 = 2columns for your first table.

If you want to show the third column, use one of these changes:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
    </td>
<tr>
```

Or

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
     &nbsp;
    </td>
<tr>
```

And, add onChange in your combo definition:

```
<select name="example" onchange="alert(this.value)">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">A</option>
</select>
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <table border="1" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:30%;max-width:30%;">
                <img src="Image.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:100px;height:50px">
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%; max-width:30%;">
                <h2> List1 </h2>
            </td>
            <td style="width:30%; max-width:30%; ">
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h2>List2: </h2>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="example" onchange="myfunction(this.value)">
                                <option value="A">A</option>
                                <option value="B">B</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
             &nbsp;
            </td>
        <tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

**Edit:** 
Change the onchange:

```
<select name="example" onchange="myfunction(this.value)">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Add this to the rest of your code:

```
<script>
  function myfunction(val){
    if(val == "A") 
      fnA();
    els if(val == "B") 
      fnB();
  }
  function fnA(){
    alert("This is the function for A");
  }
  function fnB(){
    alert("This is the function for B");
  }
// you can call fnA(); here as it is your default selection and call it by default.
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The column issue is solved but the for the combo selection change what i meant to say is . when user select "One" then it will call a function n its event and when he selects "two" than another function will be called in javascript. I want to do this type of mechnaism . Could you please let me know how to do that ?

Comment: Its bit late.. i have already done it. But ur answer is correct so i mark it answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for first question...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
 <td><img src="#" alt="Your Image" /></td>
 <td>Your Text goes here</td>
 <td>

    <table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>Your Text here</td>
<td>

    <select name="example">
         <option value="A">A</option>
         <option value="B">A</option>
    </select>

 </td>
</tr>
</table>


 </td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of posting only code please explain the code also.